# How to add item into the list with correct current datetime?

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, sharepoint

Sharepoint 2013. I am using wcf service to create items in list programmatically that contains DateTime value. This code falls with error "Invalid date/time value" on

```
item[NewsFields.Date.InternalName] = DateTime.Now;
```

Full code:

```
    public ServiceResult<bool> CreateNews()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                var list = web.GetList(Lists.LocalNewsList.ListUrl);
                var item = list.Items.Add();
                item[NewsFields.Header.InternalName] = "Test";
                item[NewsFields.Body.InternalName] = "Test";
                item[NewsFields.FullBody.InternalName] = "Test";
                item[NewsFields.Date.InternalName] = DateTime.Now;
                item.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                return new ServiceResult<bool>(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteLine("Error create test list item: {0}", ex.Message);
            _logger.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
            _logger.WriteLine("Stack trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            return new ServiceResult<bool>(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owwww. Quiet simple fix for this dummy.

```
item[NewsFields.Date.InternalName] = 
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities
         .SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```